# Change NavigationBar Reveal direction in iOS for RTL

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift4, uistoryboard

Im creating a bilingual app in iOS. My app support English and Arabic languages. The app works fine in both languages according to Device language.

LeftToRight direction for English and RightToLeft direction for Arabic.

Now I've created a setting in my app for users to switch the language irrespective of the device language i.e. user can switch app language from english to arabic and arabic to english without changing the device language. 
All viewControllers are working fine with LTR and RTL directions but the only issue is with NavigationBar Controller.

[when app is in english (correct navigationbar behaviour)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI0cC.png)

[When app is in Arabic (incorrect layout direction)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNtLJ.png)

[When device and app are in arabic(correct behaviour)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnhgt.png)

any help is appreciated.